# Retrieve values of multiple attributes of an XML element using shell scrit

Tags: shell, xmllint

I've an XML file with below format.

```
<products>
<product name="A" version="1" location="tmp">
<product name="B" version="1.2" location="tmp">
<product name="C" version="2" location="tmp">
</products>
```

I need the values of name and version attribute for each product element. Below is the desired output

Product Version

```
A         1
B         1.2
```

Below command giving me only the product name.

```
echo 'cat //products/product/@name' | xmllint --shell envinfo.xml | awk -F\" '\NR % 2 == 0 { print $2 }'
```

Output

```
A
B
C
```

Is there any way to get multiple attribute values from each element

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Isn't `xmllint` interactive when using `--shell`?

Comment: Ugly but works `cat file | awk '{print $2,$3}' | sed 's|name="||g;s|" version="| |g;s|"||g'`

Comment: Below code worked perfectly 
while read line; do name=$(echo $line | grep 'name' | grep cut -d'=' -f2 | cut -d'"' -f2) version=$(echo $line | grep 'version' | grep cut -d'=' -f3 | cut -d'"' -f2) done < filename.xml